# Group object by value type

Tags: javascript, object, grouping

I have this object:

```js
const data = {
  a: 'name',
  b: 'age',
  c: 'age',
  d: 'age',
  e: 'name',
  f: 'age'
}
```

and I want to group by values so I would like to have:

```js
const result = {
  name: ['a', 'e'],
  age: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
}
```

Is there a smart way to do that?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: you could get a bit wacky with some new js features: https://jsfiddle.net/1qLa69ou/ :P

Comment: @NickParsons Why not post that - it is the same as mine, just even terser

Comment: @mplungjan I think your answer gets the general idea across, I don't want to make things too unreadable haha (feel free to add the use of the comma operator to your answer if you'd like).

Comment: @NickParsons I did :) First time I saw this was from Nina. It was unreadable until I complained ;)

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, first time I saw it used like that was in one of Nina's answers too, it's a clever trick but I need some time to get used to it before I start using it more + decide if I like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tersest version, thanks Nick for the comma operator to save the curlies

```js
const data = { a: 'name',  b: 'age',  c: 'age',  d: 'age',  e: 'name',  f: 'age' },
 arr = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((acc, [key,value]) => ((acc[value] ??=[]).push(key), acc),{});

console.log(arr)
```

Explanations since this is interesting to add to one's arsenal

```
(acc,  // accumulator defined by the {} at the end of the statement
 [key,value]  // destructing the entries
 ) => 
 ( // bracket to set up the comma operator later
  (acc[value] ??=[])  // nullish coalescing assignment - if no acc[value] then assign an array
  .push(key)
  , acc) // comma operator returns what is after the comma
  ,{});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all the keys and check if the corresponding value has been already assigned as key to your result object; if so, push the key into the array, if not initialise it as an array.

Something like this will work:

```js
const data = { a: 'name',  b: 'age',  c: 'age',  d: 'age',  e: 'name',  f: 'age' }

const output = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  if (!output[data[key]]) {
    // new key: assign it as a 1 element array
    output[data[key]] = [key];
  } else {
    // existing key: push it into the array
    output[data[key]].push(key);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good solutions added, but could be more clear with `Object.entries` ?

```js
const data = { a: 'name',  b: 'age',  c: 'age',  d: 'age',  e: 'name',  f: 'age' }

const results = {};
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (results[value]) { 
    results[value].push(key);
  } else {
    results[value] = [key];
  }
});

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so:

```
const map = new Map;
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  const value = data[key];
  if (!map.has(value))
    map.set(value, []);
  map.get(value).push(key);
});
const result = {};
map.forEach((key, value) => {
  result[value] = key;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the least elegant in my opinion.

Comment: it's just one way to do so, which is what I've written at the beginning. There's nothing non-elegant in using a map, but other options work too.

Comment: Just running two procedures seems overkill for something this simple

Comment: yet it's the cleanest approach, as it doesn't access non existing properties; it uses what Map has been created for, and it's *strictly* compatible with typed programming languages too, so it's *one way to do so* that can be ported to *C* too.

Comment: Which of the other answers are accessing non-existing properties?

Comment: all of them. `if (!newData[value])` is an example ... but again, this is *one way to do so*, and I am sure the OP has plenty options, and we both have better things to do.

Comment: I am asking because I am curious. I never use Map myself and I find my reduce elegant and terse. Only last week did I discover one of my reduces modified the original object

Comment: on my end, I've [historically plenty of reasons](https://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/08/please-stop-reassigning-for-no-reason.html) to avoid accessing properties "*just because*", so usually I use *Map*, but here I might have used the dirty approach everyone else suggested. They all work 

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```js
const data = { a: 'name',  b: 'age',  c: 'age',  d: 'age',  e: 'name',  f: 'age' }

const newData = {};
Object.entries(data).forEach(pair => {
const [key, value] = pair;
  if (!newData[value])
    newData[value] = [];
  newData[value].push(key)
});
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: You can destruct immediately: `forEach(([key, value]) =>` however your solution is quite similar to other answers on the page